# How long before I can re-enter the UK after Youth Mobility?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens, ireland

I complied with the rules by leaving after 2 years in UK and didn't overstay.

It's been 3 months since I exited UK. I flew to the Republic of Ireland and have been a tourist doing unpaid writing and photography for a blog.

My partner lives in UK and is working. He's currently applying for residency rights and was just sent letter saying he now can apply for a National Insurance Number.

I'd like to come back to the UK as a visitor and see him. I have also registered a company in the UK so I will need to see an accountant to do the company's first tax return.

How long do I have to stay outside UK before I can come back on a tourist or any other short category visa?

I am Australian.

We noted that while flying from Belfast to London there is no passport control. What's the penalty for entering Northern Ireland and flying to London from there? What happens when you don't get a temporary passport stamp?

I have no intention of staying long term. I'm just planning on doing the tax and seeing my partner.

Comment: If you want a tourist (visit) visa, you will have to apply for one from Ireland (or wherever you are at the time). Alternatively you can attempt to enter the UK visa free. However, doing this to/from Ireland in the wrong way can land you in a lot of hot water, so tread very carefully.

Comment: what is "nin" ? is there a chance you can click "Edit" and fix the typos (missing spaces between sentences and so on), it might bring better or more answers.

Comment: Nin=national insurance number

Comment: It says on gov.UK that's Australians don't need to apply for tourist visas?

Comment: @AussieTravellerTales don't **need to** isn't the same as **"can't"**. If you wanted, you could apply for a visitor visa to the UK. I don't think you have any reason to though. I've also never heard an NI number referred to as "nin" in my life.

Comment: Realistically why would I apply for a visa when my country advice and uk advice is you don't need to? I'm not breaking the law and haven't broken any past visa rules - just don't get that ? Oh, well I lived In the UK for 2 years and heard it called a NIN mannnny mannnnny times! Its just the acronym for tax : National Insurance Number :)

Comment: edited - I wouldn't have known what a nin is either, despite having lived in the UK for well over 40 years

Comment: @AussieTravellerTales people apply for a visa to the UK even when they don't need one, because it lets them have their situation considered and approved before they got to the border. So no wasted money on flights etc. It doesn't seem relevant to you right now, no. It's recommended for people who have had trouble before. I've lived my whole life in the UK, never heard it called "NIN" and no, it doesn't mean "tax" either. An NI number is indeed somewhat related to taxes (and many other things), but it isn;t the same thing **as** tax.

Comment: lol who cares its just a word reference re nin! yup im aware what its function is, had one myself while in UK! thanks re visa application. I have to agree that this does not apply to me given Ive never had trouble at any entry worldwide, including UK. Thanks!

Comment: No one appears to have pointed out that registering a business in the UK certainly makes it seem as if you are trying to settle permanently there.

Comment: what? thousands of people register businesses in the uk from abroad. You dont even need to be int he uk to do that so, that doesnt fly.

Answer (score 8):

You are in the ROI previously in the UK on a YMS visa and you want to enter the UK via a port in the Common Travel Area.

The [answer provided by 'the other one'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80830/reentry-to-uk-after-youth-mobility-when/80844#80844) is great. +1 from me, thanks and a tip of the hat! I wanted to add that in this particular case we can turn to Border Force's Operations Manual and have a closer look.  Here's the relevant scan...

[image]

I defaced the original by adding little red thingies that trace your situation through the flowchart. You will be able to see that it ends on the result "deemed to have 7 days code 3".

So they are saying that you get 7 days more or less automatically. After that you become an overstayer of the 'inadvertent' kind (that's a bad thing). Unless they think that you intended to overstay in which case you become an illegal entrant (that's a very bad thing). In your case they would go for the latter because you have a bf in the UK which helps to  establish intent. That situation will be exacerbated because they are *already upset* about the number of Aussies who are abusing the YMS (like using the CTA loophole for example), so you can expect a difficult time *if (and only if)* you get caught.

Those outcomes only happen if you get caught inland at some event which requires your id, otherwise you're off the hook. The other downside is you may have to lie on future UK applications to prevent disclosure of illegal entry (that's a precarious position to be in).

That's a technical and 'legally precise' answer to your question.  In practical terms and for everyday knowledge, you can use ['the other one's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80830/reentry-to-uk-after-youth-mobility-when/80844#80844).

Your other question...

> How long do I have to stay outside UK before I can come back on a
>   tourist or any other short category visa?

There is no mandatory cooling-off period between YMS and visitor, you can return the same day if you want. The big problem (and I mean BIG problem) is that you will have to explain to an Immigration Officer what it's all about. And that interview can be *[hazardous](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/removal)* to your travelling plans.

NOTE: The "code 3" part is their internal shorthand that summarises the situation. The best practices on how to interpret this is to ignore it altogether.

NOTE: The ROI has their own counterpart to this flowchart and your situation there may be dubious depending upon how you entered. You should check that out as a matter of extreme urgency. You don't want to be caught out or matters will become immeasurably worse.

NOTE: Since your bf's status in the UK is apparently unstable, your interaction with an IO may attract scrutiny of his status of the hostile variety. The comment from CMaster about treading carefully is fully loaded, heed it.

NOTE: For others, the flowchart can be used for **all non-EAA nationals** coming to the UK through the ROI.

NOTE: the flowchart is not something the Border Force just dreamed up on a whim. It is a visual extract of the applicable portions of the [Immigration Rules Part 1](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk). It means everything on the chart exists with legislative authority handed down by Parliament.

Comment: So if you enter the UK for 6 months and then go to Ireland, you can only return to the UK for 7 days without flying out of the CTA?

Comment: The CTA may be great for residents of NI/RoI, but it seems to be a full-on-nightmare for travellers from outside.

Comment: @JonathanReez that situation is in the flowchart and simultaneously addressed fully by Paragraphs 20A and 20B of the rules.  It warrants a separate question.

Comment: Since the OP entered Ireland by air the OP would have passed through immigration control there and got stamped in for a 3 month visit, which is now apparently exhausted. Since the OP's last recorded entry to the CTA, and the one that gave the OP visitor status, is through Ireland is there not a reading of the flow chart that gives the OP three months instead? I agree with @CMaster.

Comment: Great flowchart enclosed thank you! I just have one question, why all the intimidation from Immigration, when you do clearly follow the rules? I don't have any intention of overstaying - with or without a bf. If its 7 days - that's fine! But why should I be panicked to enter the UK when as you say, theres no cooling off period after respecting the Youth Mobility guidelines? I'm coming to do my tax - with or without a bf. Also, UK is best port for me to exit to next destination. Whether that be Asia or Europe. Just feels very 'feeling based', and unnecessarily complicated. Not black and white!

Comment: @AussieTravellerTales it's policy https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2013/oct/10/immigration-bill-theresa-may-hostile-environment

Comment: @Dennis no, please look at it again in the part that says 'previously in the UK'

Comment: Weird that I only get 7 days despite respecting the prior visa exit date, being and staying gone for 3 months. Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @AussieTravellerTales your comment here "* If I stayed there for a time, would I then have permission to come back to UK for a few weeks, given that 6 months (by then), had passed? Also, would I get a stamp - coming from Europe, not ROI...?I want to do things the right way here and if it means I don't go to UK for longer than 7 days - that's fine. But when will I be eligible to visit for longer?*" would make a good question. Otherwise take it up with Parliament. The answer stands "AS IS"

Comment: yes lets see what input i can get posting that very question.

Answer (score 4):

The Republic of Ireland and the UK (and the Isle of Mann and Channel Islands) are part of the Common Travel Area (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area)

A flight from Dublin to England is treat the same as a domestic flight. Whether you fly from Belfast or Dublin makes no difference.

There is no immigration check when travelling between the two however to board a plane you will still probably have to show some ID, which is usually taken to mean just a passport (though a EU driving license or ID card may be OK. unsure).

I wouldn't risk going to Belfast just to fly over if I was you. It is not inconceivable that this could lead to you being flagged in a system and getting a spot check. If you're flying from Dublin to the UK and all isn't OK you can put this down to you being unsure about your status, nice and innocent.
Going up to Belfast just to fly over when there are perfectly good and cheap flights from Dublin....that seems like you're trying to evade them.

Comment: I haven't had to show ID for several flights between GB and NI. Although I possible provided passport number to the online check in.

Comment: @CMaster in this day and age, there is utterly no way an unidentified traveler would be allowed to fly - a domestic 737 can still do a lot of damage...

Comment: Luck of the draw I think. I certainly had one flight last year where I flew between two schengen countries and never had my ID checked once. But then on the other hand I've also had a inter-schengen flight where everyone got full security checks as if we were coming from abroad.

Comment: @Moo. I've done this several times this year. Not one ID check from end to end.

Comment: @CMaster not even when you buy the ticket? I dont believe that, the British government as it is, would allow *anyone* unidentified on an airborne plane over British territory in the current state of heightened awareness...

Comment: As I said, I may have provided the passport number when checking in online. However, I never showed the ID to anybody, and so I could in theory have used any old ID number there.

Comment: Flagged on an internal flight? Based just on the name?

Comment: based on being australian and without a valid visa.
I do think its more likely than not that there would be no trouble but I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: Hey Guys so just want to clarify if it helps at all - sorry for crappy typing and spacing before, was on a ipad that auto-corrects and its so annoying. So I entered UK on Youth Mobility Visa in July 2014. I exited in July 2014. In Dec 2015 I started a company. My bf is in London with a view to get right of residency - hes just been granted a National Insurance Number and right to work. Home Office comments he may work while waiting for their final response to his residence application. Given that I respected my VISA and left in July, did not overstay I entered ROI & got a 90 day tourist stamp

Comment: Since being a tourist here in ROI I have done photography in Dublin, Galway and rural Ireland. I genuinely need to do my UK company tax and of COURSE I want to see my bf, but even if I didn't have a bf I would still need considerable advice about preparing my 1st uk company tax return and also submitting hardcopy receipts for analysis and to get a template for future tax returns. Anyway! I'm not trying to dodge uk immigration I just don't understand the cryptic nature of Youth Movbility because once you respect the rules and leave, if you have a real need to return (say business) why cant you?

Comment: Is it better for me to go to another country - for me as an Australian, I can get 90 days in Schengen area. As I was told, ROI is NOT Schengen. Therefore I could get 90days as a tourist in say France, Italy or Germany. If I stayed there for a time, would I then have permission to come back to UK for a few weeks, given that 6 months (by then), had passed? Also, would I get a stamp - coming from Europe, not ROI...?I want to do things the right way here and if it means I don't go to UK for longer than 7 days - that's fine. But when will I be eligible to visit for longer? That's what I don't get.

Comment: should read exited in July 2016!

Comment: Coming from Europe you will go through proper immigration control and get a stamp by default yes. Though I'm sure even flying from Ireland you could seek out immigration on the UK side and get that sorted. No idea on the how long you have to wait side, sorry.