# Does an Australian need a visa to enter the UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, tourist-visas, australian-citizens

Do I need a visa or stamp to enter UK from the Republic of Ireland? I have a 90-day tourist visa stamped in my passport on arrival.

If I get the bus from Dublin to Belfast, and then a flight from Belfast to London, do I need anything in advance?

I read that Australians don't need anything ahead of time for a standard 90-day tourist entry. Is that right?

I also head that there is a 6-month visa for Australians. Does that exist? How do you get it?

Comment: Yeah, you've gotten things wrong.Start here: https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration But note that as mentioned in your other question, it's very easy for a traveller to get themselves in trouble moving between the UK and the RoI.
Also, the RoI does not give out Visas on Arrival, so that probably isn;t a visa in your passport.

Comment: Given the circumstances noted in your other question, the usual answer to this question (i.e. you wouldn't normally need a visa) is unlikely to be helpful to you.

Comment: You have an entry stamp that grants you 90 days' stay in the Republic of Ireland, but it's not a visa.

Comment: @phoog nice one.

Comment: whats with the cattiness on this site? If you introduce a new acronym you get made to feel like u invented it. If you try to figure out a travel situation you get ganged up. Really guys? Seriously? Seems like a little clique.

Comment: Look if you want to help people do that. But dont make people feel like idiots for trying to learn and do the right thing. Just makes the site come off as elitist and snobby. The stamp I got upon entry to ROI says 'temporary permission ' permitted to ireland for a maximum of 90 days. If the terminology is wrong - dont beat a dead horse. just say so! 

Also if I asked the question again its because i feel im getting spoken to like a fool and its totally unwarranted.

Comment: Why is it easy for a traveller to get in trouble from ROI to UK or vice versa ? Im not intending to do anything illegal or wrong as ive stated numerous times. What the heck is with the side eye! Im trying to get advice - instead Im getting told everything im getting wrong. Also re ROI aussies dont need visas so whats wrong with an entry stamp? Why with the overkill on visas when it cleary states on Aus and UK advice that aussies dont need visas unless youve incurred past refusals and had issues!? Just making unnecesary drama here honestly.

Answer (score 1):

The UK and ROI form the "common travel area".

If you enter the UK from outside the common travel area and the landing interview deems you are a legitimate visitor you normally get 6 months "leave to enter". No visa is required.

If you enter via the ROI things get more complicated. Your status depends on your previous UK immigration history and how you entered Ireland. [The answer to your other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80830/how-long-before-i-can-re-enter-the-uk-after-youth-mobility) has a flowchart which helps you figure out what your status will be.

Also based on your other question be aware that coming back as a visitor soon after you left on a youth mobility visa will make the boarder guard more suspicious. You may have an uphill struggle trying to convince the border gaurd that you are a genunine visitor who intends to leave on time and does not intend to work.

Comment: Thanks Peter! This is what I don't get and find unnecessarily frustrating for international travellers. Why not make it clean cut to stop the bullsh*t? As in why cant they say okay! After a YM Visa you must remain outside uk for minimum of 6 months. That's clear - plain  - no hassle. Why no guideline or policy with tangible dates? Anyway I have no intention to stay illegally and work. I have my UK business already set up I can work from anywhere in the world. Just want to get specific UK tax lodging advice plus professional prep. And see my bf. What time passing is reasonable? 3 months? 6?12?