# How do I get a passport stamp when traveling from Ireland to the UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, ireland, passport-stamps

How do I get my passport stamped with an entry stamp to UK from Republic of Ireland?

I need to be able to show my exit from Ireland. I'm not an EU/EEA citizen.

Comment: How are you crossing the border?

Comment: Exit by air via a third country. Eg. Dublin -> X -> London.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? The question is legitimate

Answer (score 7):

> How do I get my passport stamped with an entry stamp to UK from
>   Republic of Ireland?

You don't.  If you try, they will refuse because leave-to-enter can only be issued at an authorised primary control point and those places cannot be approached from inland. Moreover, it's a sackable offence to 'stamp someone in' inland (that can only be done by applying to the Home Office).

If there are any date calculations to be done they will use the start date on your ROI entry stamp. If you have not been in the UK previously, and you are in the UK more than 90 days beyond the ROI entry stamp, you will become either an overstayer or illegal entrant (depending upon how they caught you).

> I need to be able to show my exit from Ireland. I'm not an EU/EEA
>   citizen.

Why? If your leave in the ROI has been entirely spent and you go to the UK (as pointed out above), you are automatically an overstayer or illegal entrant. The UK Border Force  uses the original entry stamp into the [Common Travel Area](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQwbPitYbQAhXBJsAKHcb7BjYQFgglMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCommon_Travel_Area&usg=AFQjCNEhRMt2bsRgPJLIkg5UHx16EwYPlg&sig2=ouWSEEA_jwX9S2Dr4_20Dg&bvm=bv.137132246,d.d24) as their reference point.  On the other hand, if you have unspent leave there is no need to document anything.

The canonical advice if you *absolutely* need to document your arrival in the UK (i.e., a spouse or student or work permit holder) is to channel hop outside the CTA, France or Belgium being the best options.

NOTE: You can see the chart from their operations manual at: [How long before I can re-enter the UK after Youth Mobility?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80830/how-long-before-i-can-re-enter-the-uk-after-youth-mobility/80860#80860) the red thingies do not apply to your case. Based on what you wrote, your path ends at 'deemed to 3 months Code 3'. The 3 months is from the date you entered the CTA (you do not 'automatically' get an extension).

NOTE: For completeness sake...  Yes, as mentioned above you can apply to the Home Office. Doing this route is *wildly adventurous* and emphatically not recommended without a [solicitor](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/) making representations for you.

---

NOTE: this answer is **time-limited and heavily affected by Brexit**. [ILPA](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/) prepared evidence for the [House of Lords’ Select Committee on the
European Union](http://www.parliament.uk/hleu)  in a briefing called [ILPA Evidence for the House of Lords’ Select Committee on the European Union for its enquiry into the impact on the relationship between the United Kingdom and Ireland following the vote by UK
citizens to leave the European Union](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/data/resources/32543/16.09.30-ILPA-Evidence-for-the-House-of-Lords-Select-Committee-on-the-European-Union-for-its-enquiry-into-the-impact-on-the-relationship-between-the-UK-and-Ireland-following-the-vote-by-UK-citizens-to-leave-the-EU.pdf) for a list of impacts.

See also [Agreement for the sharing of visa, immigration, and nationality information](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/agreement-between-the-uk-and-usa-for-the-sharing-of-visa-immigration-and-nationality-information--2)

Comment: This answer is correct. This is also why, if you want to stay in the UK for 3-6 months, you need to enter the CTA at a British, and not Irish, port of entry - as at Irish ones you'll only be granted a 3-month leave

Comment: The chart doesn't say when the 3 month leave starts, but I understand the chart is a representation of [The Immigration (Control of Entry Through Republic of Ireland) Order 1972](http://legislation.data.gov.uk/uksi/1972/1610/made/data.htm?wrap=true) which says that under the chart's 3 month conditions "the period for which he may remain in the United Kingdom shall not be more than three months from the date on which he entered the United Kingdom" from Ireland. It seems like the 3 months (or 7 days) is additional to whatever you spent in Ireland?

Comment: @Dennis v nice research, that's an SI which got amended when the ROI joined the EU the following year, I will find the link, but great that you located the original.