# Enter Ireland as non-visa national and proceed to UK - what is the allowed duration of stay?

Tags: visas, uk, ireland

I am a [non-visa national](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/study/international/immigration/othervisas/studentvisitor/non_visa_nationals/) planning to visit Ireland and the UK with entry through Ireland and onward to UK without passing through immigration control.

Does the duration of stay I am given in Ireland cover my total stay in the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area)? Basically if I am unfortunate and say given only 1 week upon entry into Ireland (instead of the standard 90 days), do I have to depart the UK before the 1 week is up, or do I automatically get the standard 90 day leave to enter once I cross over into UK?

This much I know:

> When someone transits via Dublin into the UK they do so on a 90 day leave-to-enter issued by the Republic of Ireland. This allows the holder to move about the Common Travel Area.
>
> The leave-to-enter **does not** automatically become a six-month UK
>   leave-to-enter by crossing a border. Regardless of where they are the
>   person becomes an overstayer on the 91st day.

Comment: Gayot has posted a convenient chart here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/80860/9009

Comment: @JonathanReez In the chart, what is _Pax is subject to control_ in the top left corner?

Comment: It basically means one is an overstayer.

Comment: @JonathanReez The [chart](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/262658/annexi.pdf) is very instructive. Would my interpretation that  the visitor gets 3 months (Code 3) correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Pax is subject to control = detention and removal. And the key word in the chart is "deemed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [answer](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/262658/annexi.pdf) at the UK.GOV website I found. You get **three months** in the UK.

[image]